# Http Filters in Angular

Tags: angular, filter, aop

do Angular has the concept of http-filters, like there is such concept in popular backend frameworks?

I mean following: if I want to access some rest-point at the server, my request goes through several filters in the backend e.g. authorization filter, log-filter etc...In my angular application I want to do the same thing. E.g. I want to filter all responses from the server for error handlings. In the case if the user is not logged in and he wants to access a secured url, he will get the 401 error. So I want the filter on the angular side to redirect the user to the login page but I do not want to implement this logic in each service.

So maybe there already exist some libraries in angular, which support aspect oriented programming or something like this?

Kind regards

Andrej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Angular's http interceptors to achieve that. Check out the docs.
[Http Interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)